# Detect jumping with accelerometer (use magnitude to count) in android

Tags: android, accelerometer, gravity, motion, motion-detection

I would like to detect jump in android, after studied:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

the magnitude seems to be a better factor of detect jump instead of X/Y/Z acceleration, the idea is whenever magnitude change from 9.8 to 0 , then count it as a jump

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){    
  final float alpha = 0.8;

  // Isolate the force of gravity with the low-pass filter.
  gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
  gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
  gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

  // Remove the gravity contribution with the high-pass filter.
  linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
  linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
  linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
}
```

The problem is , how to obtain the magnitude and make such comparsion?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android get normalized acceleration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565401/android-get-normalized-acceleration)